# Is it possible to get rid of unwanted console messages in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

Messages in my eclipse (testNG & selenium) projects are getting so much now that wanted outputs from sysout command are getting lost between them. This started recently. They were never these much. I heard there is a way to get rid of the unwanted warning messages or reduce them, at least. How can this be possibly achieved?

I get duplicates of messages like:

```
    [BaseMessageSender] Connection established, starting reader thread
    [BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread waiting for an admin message
    [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [GenericMessage ==> suiteCount:1, 
    
    testCount:1]
    TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@11531931: 80 ms
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@35bbe5e8: 19 ms
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3f0ee7cb: 7 ms
    TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 1 ms
    [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Filepath\....
```

Comment: I suggest you configure TestNG to use a logging framework such as slf4j, in which you can specify the severity of each message and (for example) suppress the ones below "warning".

Comment: What if you change the log level to 0 and disable verbose + debug? http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-create-launch

Comment: @ Julien Herr, thanks. This log level configuration worked like a charm. Super!

Comment: @Julien Herr, please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386805/webdriver-can-login-in-chrome-not-in-firefox-unable-to-find-owning-document?noredirect=1#comment68047438_40386805

Answer (score 1):

right click on the file you want to run ,then click on the `Run Configurations` then make sure verbose and Debug checkbox is unchecked .

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGz4F.png)